Execution failed for task ':expo-permissions:compileReleaseKotlin'. Task :react-native-reanimated:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a] | EXPO
I am trying to build my expo app using
eas build --platform android

But I am getting the above error, It works fine for me running my expo app locally and no error is shown.
The app is built by using expo and thus don't know where the problem is occurring since every solution is for react native.
I have tried moving my folder to a shorter url path but it also didn't work.
error log
